# Open sharepoint document in client application rather than browser - Client side

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

We are having web application in which we have used Rest Api to get and show all documents from document library. Now there is a requirement to open those document in client application(desktop word, ppt etc). As currently we click on document it opens in browser, but we want to open in client application. (to be implemented client side)
Please help.

Comment: changing the advanced settings for the library to open in client application does not fix the issue?

Comment: Additionally, does the URL that gets created have `?web=1` on it? If so, you can strip that to prevent it from opening in browser I believe.